# How to play audio file from URI using ffmpeg files in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

HI all,

I am working on playing audio from URI using ffmpeg shared library in android.

I configured android-ndk and added ffmpeg shared library to project and able to compile the project using cygwin.

In ffmpeg library i see ffmpeg.c file, i donot know how i can use this file to implement audio player in my activity.

Please help me on this issue.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check the last comment. Perhaps it helps.
[Using FFmpeg / FFplay for audio playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000385/playing-audio-with-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 1):

First, Use ffmpeg to open the URI and read frames and decode to raw PCM data, you can take a look at ffplay.c about the decoding part.

Next, using the Android AudioTrack class to play the raw PCM data, there is a tutorial: [fun with audiotrack](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=228)

Good luck!

Comment: your link is dead, I also need that how to control ffmeg library from my activity.