# Playing audio with FFMPEG

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, android-ndk

I have been trying to port FFMPEG (for playing audio) into Android using NDK. I have had some success

- I could build FFMPEG and link it via NDK.
- I could call `avcodec_decode_audio3()` and decode a given audio file.

So here I have a audio buffer output from the function. How do I play this now? Any ffmpeg guys can tell me the exact steps to decode and play audio. I am really clueless of what to do with the audio buffers created I got from `avcodec_decode_audio3()`.

thanks a lot.

Comment: You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645041/ffmpeg-for-a-android-using-tutorial-ffmpeg-and-android-mk) or maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android).

Comment: I have gone thru those sometime back. Those just help on "building" ffmpeg for Android, which I have done already. I don't know exactly how to 'use' FFMPEG library functions.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the **FFmpeg as an audio playback tool** you can untilize [FFplay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html) (available for Windows and for Linux).

It's as simple as: `ffplay <input audio track>` 
The audio track must be of a supported format, meaning you will need some libraries.

1. If you want something for a **Windows** system, then just download the
   builds [here](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), and then put the executable in your environment
   variable path. One can also go the hard way and download the source code and build. But why bother?
2. In case you're using something sporting some **Linux**, including Raspbian [this
   link](https://www.jeffreythompson.org/blog/2014/11/13/installing-ffmpeg-for-raspberry-pi/) describes how to get libraries and then enable then in the
   FFmpeg build. The FFmpeg build will also include FFplay. I have tested this and it seems to work for me.
3. In both cases you will need to have a **C compiler installed** in order to tackle the make commands.

**An implementation example using FFplay processes in python3:**

I am working on a personal project utilizing a RaspberryPi as more or less a fancy mp3 player doorbell type IoT device. It plays Darude Sandstorm on full blast for anyone ringing the doorbell. But it also has a twist. It's called [DarudeDoorBell](https://github.com/VladLimbean/DaruDoorBell).

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a videoplayer on android based on ffmpeg. You can use AudioTrack class to play audio onto device.

EDIT :

In Java create an audiotrack object

```
AudioTrack track;
bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize, mode);

//Play audio clip
track.play();

while(stream_is_over){
//Copy the decoded raw buffer from native code to "buffer" .....
............
track.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
}
```

Comment: Can you share some info on that? I would be greatly interested!

Comment: This answer is the bread of a sandwich and completely missing the meat.